# Ruby on Rails - Whitelist some IP-adresses to see Full error reports on production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, production, error-reporting

In `Rails 4` from **config > environments > production.rb** by changing: `config.consider_all_requests_local= true`, Devs can *turn on* **Full error reports** on production.

Is it possible to *whitelist* some IP-adresses so **Full error reports** is `true` for these IPs while for rest would be `false`.

I know I can read the `production` logs from server logs, but its a hassle log in to server and remember the correct path and not to mention its readability is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rails will allow you to do that. However, you can use [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gem to whitelist IP's for logs

Comment: `better_errors` is only for development and not production, isn't that right?